# I got error in 'make' gcc-5.3.0 package as referred in Linux from scratch

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I get the following error when making `gcc`:

```
Makefile:2154: recipe for target 's-attrtab' failed
make[2]: *** [s-attrtab] Killed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.3.0/build/gcc'
Makefile:4105: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.3.0/build'
Makefile:858: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Note : this may help someone [compatibility issue]
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gcc-s-attrtab-error-4175557586/

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue[1](http://dustint.com/post/669/gentoo-gcc-recipe-for-target-s-attrtab-failed). The reason for this error is the fact the system is running out of memory. In my case it was caused because I ran `make -j 48` and these 48 jobs were too much.

Decreasing the job number to 24 fixed this problem. In other words:

1. increase your memory *or*
2. reduce the jobs using the `-j` make switch

[1](http://dustint.com/post/669/gentoo-gcc-recipe-for-target-s-attrtab-failed) This post helped me then to fix the problem: http://dustint.com/post/669/gentoo-gcc-recipe-for-target-s-attrtab-failed

Answer (score 0):

This is how i installed it on ubuntu 14.04  (gcc 5)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
sudo update-alternatives 
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Answer (score 0):

---

The most common errors with the LFS gcc are caused by using a wrong shell. /bin/sh must be a link to bash !

If the wrong shell was used : Start from scratch with binutils.

"Askforhelp" : http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter01/askforhelp.html → 1.5.1. →  the essential things to include in any request for help are → ... The host distribution and version being used to create LFS.

Please show the output from $ `bash version-check.sh`

---